# Angular: Why can't I inject $provide directly into $get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I assume there's a straightforward (maybe trivial) answer for this that I just haven't wrapped my head around.

Why does this do what I want -- that is, inject a reference to `$provide` into my service:

```
angular.module('error_reporting', [])
       .provider('RaygunLogger', function() {
           var provide = undefined;

           this.setProvide = function(p){
                provide = p;
           }

           this.$get = function() {
               // use $provide in p
           };
       })
       .config(function(RaygunLoggerProvider, $provide) {
           RaygunLoggerProvider.setProvide($provide);
       });
```

while this produces an error of the form `Unknown provider: $provideProvider <- $provide <- RaygunLogger <- RaygunLogger`?

```
angular.module('error_reporting', [])
       .provider('RaygunLogger', function() {
           this.$get = function($provide) {
                // use $provide
           };
       });
```

Is `RaygunLogger.$get()` running before the injector is set up?  I presume this is an order-of-operations issue, where I need to wait until the module config phase before I can inject `$provide`, but I don't know where to verify that in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$provide` is only available during the config phase. Provider's `$get` function is run after the config phase to create the thing the provider provides.

At this point, you cannot do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To use it inside `$get` your normally start your provider function with

```
var self = this;
```

and in `$get` (factory) definition you use `self`.

E.g

```
angular.module('foo',[])
.provider('myFoo', function myFooProviderFn() {
    var self = this;
    self._debug = false;
    self.setDebug = function() { self._debug = true; }
    self.$get = ['$location', function($location) {
        self.setDebug();
    });
});
```

Its wrong to think you cannot use it inside your `$get`. As such the actual pure provider instance can only be accessed and manipulated during the config phase. The rationale behind this design is probably that providers are thought of to be some mechanism to configure factories.

More from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) (Provider recipe)

Comment: Keeping a copy of `this` in `self` does exactly nothing to prevent the Unknown Provider exception I'm asking about.  I want to know why I can't inject `$provide` directly into `$get`; I'm not concerned about the binding of `this` inside inner functions.

Comment: The provider instance is only available to angular during the config phase...not any other directly...this is by design.